# How do I build and install a plugin for KDevelop?

Tags: plugins, kdevelop

In particular, I am trying to install [kdev-control-flow-graph](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/devtools/plugins/kdev-control-flow-graph/repository)

I have managed to clone the source from git, cmake the source to build a kdevcontrolflowgraphview.so installed to /usr/local/lib, but when I restart kdevelop, I can find no sign of the plugin!

Under the Loaded Plugins window, it doesn't show up, and I can't seem to find a way to tell it about the existence of the new plug-in.

I am running KDevelop Version 4.2.3 using KDE Development Platform 4.7.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that "/usr/local/lib" is in your KDEDIRS var, and run "kbuildsyscocoa4 --noincremental"

If that doesn't work, perhaps the plugin's .desktop file needs to have its version modified.

Also note that you aren't running KDE Development Platform 4.7.2 because that doesn't exist (you probably mean KDE 4.7.2), you should be running KDevplatform 1.2.3.